# Except channel getting null status in mesibo iOS flutter

Tags: flutter

Mesibo skd is not connecting to flutter iOS ,I try all the possibilities but can't able to connect mesibo in iOS flutter ,always getting chanel null not show status code .

#flutter #iosflutter #Flutter

Import file manually

Answer (score 0):

First, kindly verify that you have added valid dependency with version or not like.

```
dependencies:
  mesibo: ^0.0.12
```

After that, Make sure that you have initialised the SDK properly in root file with valid API key as bellow.

```
import 'package:mesibo/mesibo.dart';

void main() {
  Mesibo.initialize(
    'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
    'com.yourapp.package.name',
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Next, you may have to add permissions to info.plist file as bellow for camera and microphone.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Camera permission is required for video calls</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Microphone permission is required for audio calls</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
  <string>voip</string>
  <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Note: In case, if you still face any error the kindly check in the common asked questions in documentation and if you don't get any solution from that then you can raise query to Mesibo support Team for assistance.

Comment: there is no package remains in pub.dev,we have to implement manually setup